# Weka classify new instance with loaded model?

Tags: classification, weka, svm, smo

I'm trying to classify a new instance given a weka model, doing

`java weka.classifiers.functions.SMO  -T /Users/pboix/Desktop/MovieClassifier/src/testDescriptors.csv -l /Users/pboix/Desktop/MovieClassifier/Models/binaryAdventure.model`

but I keep getting the exception "java.lang.Exception: training and test set are not compatible"

I have already checked the trainset from the model and the test set, and they both have the same number of attributes, following the same order. The test set has an empty class value (""), which is the one that I want to determine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would check that the attribute values also appear in the same order as the training dataset.  If you are POSITIVE that the sets are compatible, you could simply copy the header of the training dataset and use it to replace the header of the test dataset (the header being everything before the instances).